# UITextfield delegate responding to all text fields

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
var departureField = UITextField()
var arrivalField = UITextField()
var dateField = UITextField()
```

I am setting the delegate for `arrivalField` and not for the other fields

```
arrivalField.delegate = self
```

I have the following delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. When I tap departureField or dateField, both are responding to the method. I have only set the delegate for the arrival field, and I only want to respond to the arrival text field. Am I missing something completely?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftDate

class FlightStatusRouteViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var date = NSDate()

    var departureField: UITextField!
    var arrivalField: UITextField!
    var dateField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.createUI(self.view)
    }

    func createUI(parent: UIView) {
        let height = CGFloat(45)
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        let btn = createButton("Submit")

        departureField = self.createInput("Departure Airport")
        arrivalField = self.createInput("Arrival Airport")
        dateField = self.createInput("Departure Date")

        departureField.delegate = nil
        arrivalField.delegate = self
        dateField.delegate = nil

        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        dateField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "updateDate:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        parent.addSubview(departureField)
        parent.addSubview(arrivalField)
        parent.addSubview(dateField)
        parent.addSubview(btn)

        self.createTapGesture(btn, action: "submitForm:")

        dateField.text = date.toString(format: DateFormat.Custom("EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"))

        dateField.snp_makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(parent)
            make.right.equalTo(parent)
            make.top.equalTo(parent).offset(10)
            make.height.equalTo(height)
        }

        departureField.snp_makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(parent)
            make.right.equalTo(parent)
            make.height.equalTo(height)
            make.top.equalTo(dateField.snp_bottom).offset(10)
        }

        arrivalField.snp_makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(parent)
            make.right.equalTo(parent)
            make.top.equalTo(departureField.snp_bottom).offset(10)
            make.height.equalTo(height)
        }

        btn.snp_makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(arrivalField.snp_bottom).offset(20)
            make.left.equalTo(parent)
            make.right.equalTo(parent)
            make.height.equalTo(height)
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let searchVc = SearchAirportsTableViewController()
        searchVc.searchField = textField
        self.presentViewController(searchVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }

    internal func updateDate(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        date = sender.date
        self.dateField.text = sender.date.toString(format: DateFormat.Custom("EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"))
    }
}
```

---

```
func createInput(placeholder: String) -> UITextField {
    let textfield = TextField()
    let fonts = FlySAAFonts()

    textfield.placeholder = placeholder
    textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textfield.font = UIFont(name: fonts.std, size: 14)!
    textfield.backgroundColor = FlySAAColors.offWhite
    textfield.tintColor = FlySAAColors.darkGry
    textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    textfield.layer.borderWidth = 0

    return textfield
}
```

Comment: Where did you assign the delegate, show your code Tyrone.

Comment: You're certainly messing something up. Make sure that the other two textfields' delegates aren't being set somewhere.

Comment: You can show screen or  some code set frame for you textField?

Comment: Added the code. Controller is pretty small.

Comment: Please show us `createInput()` as well.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you're setting the delegates to `nil` after `createInput`.

Comment: Based on your code it shouldn't make delegate callbacks for `departireField` and `dateField`. I have to ask, how do you know that callbacks are being made for these textfields? What are the symptoms?

Comment: @TamásZahola it hits textFieldShouldBeginEditing, because it presents SearchAirportsTableViewController. It is strange.

Comment: @TYRONEMICHAEL okay, but inside `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is `textField` really `dateField` or `departureField` ?

Comment: @TamásZahola I am using IQKeyboardManager. For some reason it is conflicting with the textfield delegates. By removing it, it works. FFS!

Answer (score 0):

You can check outlet on storyboard.

or in

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing
```

you check if

```
textField == departureField || textField == dateField
return false
```

Comment: He can't have the delegate assigned on a storyboard b/c he created the textfields in code.

Comment: @TamásZahola you right. hmm, but you can check like above :D

Comment: yeah, but it only cures the symptoms, not the problem. Still, it's a good practice to make checks like the above in delegate callbacks, and in the default case do something like `NSAssert(NO, @"Unhandled textfield!")` to not let bugs slip through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the desired behavior. Inside your delegate method you can compare the text fields to see how you want to act based on which field it is. `if textField == departureTextField` and then do what you want.

Comment: Nope. He said he only assigned the delegate for one of the textfields.

Comment: Yea just saw that, sorry. But you can still check in the delegate method to ensure you're getting behavior for just the desired field.

Comment: Exactly. I do this every time and put an `NSAssert(NO, ...)` in the final `else` to abort if I forgot to handle something.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) and I never read the README.md properly. The solution can be found [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager#doing-custom-work-on-textfield-with-returning-no-in-textfieldshouldbeginediting-delegate-).

Comment: you should have mentioned in your question that you are using IQKeyboardManager

Comment: @TYRONEMICHAEL hehe, yeah. Why would it have anything to do with `UITextFields`? :D Anyway, happy programming, take care!